# How to get rid of imperfections after applying subsurf?

Tags: modifiers, nurbs-surface

I'm trying to model a simple sofa in blender but after I applied subdivision surface modifier i got that nasty gap. On the other side it looks good.

[image: blender image 1]

[image]

here ^ is how it looks in edit mode, there are not two objects but one so moving the small part in won't do.

PS: no need for elaborate stuff since I'm using it only as a prop, it was not intended to be a high quality object in the first place, so any solutions will do (even if it's not 'by the book'). Thank you!

Comment: Can you post a .blend?

Comment: Try selecting various edges and apply mean crease: Shift-E

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I managed to re-create that edge loop and I was more careful not to go too far with it, so it's fixed I think.

Comment: Use of supporting geometry or proximity loops allows you to control the sharpness of edges when using subsurf. Watch: http://cgcookie.com/blender/2013/06/21/tips-creating-sharp-edges-modeling/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve it!

I deleted the vertical edge loop (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd>) then <kbd>X</kbd> *→ Edge Loop*
Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to make another vertical loop cut and I was more careful not to slide it as far.

This is how it looks now

[image]

This is how it looks in the edit mode with the new edge loop

[image]

I don't know if it's the right thing to do but it worked for me!